# How can I bundle my JSON API data into one dictionary?

Tags: python, json, django, dictionary, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to package my API data into one GET request simply using standard libraries python.

```
class GetData(APIView):
    
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        urls = [url_1,
                url_2,
                url_3,
                url_4
                ] 

        data_bundle = []
        for x in urls:
            response = requests.get(x, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}).json()
            data_bundle.append(response)
            return Response(data_bundle, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

The return response has to be JSON data, I'm trying to get it to work but it seems like the response data seems to be overiding eachother? How can I properly create a JSON dictionary of dictionaries.

I've tried switching `data_bundle` to an empty dictionary instead of a list. However that just caused an error saying:

`ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 8; 2 is required`

Is there a simple way to accomplish this that I'm missing?
Thank you for the help.

Comment: Can you give an example of what the data you get look like, and how you would want it to look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class GetData(APIView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        urls = [url_1,
                url_2,
                url_3,
                url_4
                ] 

        data_bundle = []
        for x in urls:
            response = requests.get(x, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}).json()
            data_bundle.append(response)
        return Response(data_bundle, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

maybe this will help dont use return in body of for cycle. And data will not override each other

Comment: Ah yes, such a silly mistake, thank you for helping me figure out what was going wrong.